# OneDrive is stuck on "a file is blocking all uploads"

Tags: onedrive

For the past week my OneDrive for Business is showing a red "x" and when I click it I see an error message that says "a file problem is blocking all uploads". When I press on the error, a popup window comes up that is supposed to show me the problematic file. However, this window is blank.

[image: "a file problem is blocking all uploads"]
[image: window is blank]

I tried turning off and restarting, rebooting the computer, and pause and restart OneDrive.

Comment: What have changed in the last two weeks in your computer and around your computer(like internet provider, router, etc)? You aren't really providing a lot of info, You know?

Comment: OneDrive has a problem when the total length of the path exceeds 255 characters. To check on that, use this PowerShell command : `cmd /c dir /s /b |? {$_.length -gt 250}`.

Comment: The problematic Win10v1809 release went out approximately that time - did you update on the machine where you're having the issue?

Comment: Hi guys, 1) nothing changes in the environment; 2) tried the command line but the command window pop up for a second and then disappears; 3) I am using win8 pro not win10.any other ideas anyone?

Answer (score -1):

I had a colleague with this issue today. In our case the folder he was saving to had a single space at the end. For some reason that space was causing all the issues. Once he deleted it, everything synced fine again.

Comment: How did your colleague find the problem?